# 4 блока по центру

Tags: html, css

Есть **div**, который содержит блоки..

```
<div class="blocks">
 <div class="black"></div>
 <div class="black"></div>
 <div class="black"></div>
 <div class="black"></div>
 <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

и эти блоки должны отображаться по центру..

```
.blocks {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 261px;
  height: 325px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}
```

но не отображаются.. они сьежают влево!!
что я делаю не так???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум у вас разница между `black` и `block`.

Во-вторых задний фон у блоков белый. Поэтому ничего не видно.

А в целом, пора переходить на флексы. Удобно.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/

```css
.blocks {
/*
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 80%;
  */
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  /*float: left;*/
  padding: 24px;
  width: 261px;
  height: 325px;
 /* background: #FFFFFF;*/
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: на black не обращайте внимания.. в коде все правильно, здесь ошибся...

Comment: да я  тоже пробовал с флексом, НО в таком случае блоки не переносятся... они все в один ряд.. а мне нужно чтоб если есть 4 то пятый переносился под низ

Comment: @Вадим в таком случае можно делать ограничение главного контейнера по ширине и делать `flex-wrap: wrap`